# Jar autostart with Registry entry doesn’t work

Tags: java, windows, registry, keylistener

I want to autostart a .jar file with a globalKeyListener for some automatisation. Cause of this I created an autostart entry for the current user in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\run (simplified) where I put my jar file, but it doesn’t work. Can you explain me why and how to fix it? I don’t want to do it with a .bat file

Comment: "where I put my jar file" how? Just the file name? `java -jar whatever.jar`? How?

Comment: javaw -jar C:\Users\name\eclipse-workspace\project\myjar.jar Just for testing

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't very useful. Figure out where windows logs this stuff. I'd start by turning that `javaw` into an absolute path.

Comment: “It doesn’t work” means there is no Java process in the task manager cause Windows doesn’t execute my jar  even though I try it with an absolute path